# Module properties Elixir

Tags: erlang, elixir

I am new in Elixir/Erlang programming.

How can I implement module attributes for Elixir module, so user of my module can set in module constructor.

For example,

```
defmodule Config do
    some_property: nil
    other_property: nil

    def constructor(one, two) do
        some_property = one
        other_property = two
    end

    def get_property_one do 
        some_property
    end
end
```

Thank you

Comment: In addition to the answer below, you might consider that default getters/setters (even in OO) are a little bit of a code smell, i. e. they sort of break encapsulation because by default they're revealing internal detail of the class. Nothing inherently wrong with getters/setters--they just need to be used carefully.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Elixir modules are not classes and variables defined inside them are not properties, so there are no such things as constructors and destructors. Elixir is based on Erlang, so firstly, I would recommend some reading about Erlang and object oriented programming:

- [Why OO Sucks by Joe Armstrong](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/OO_programming/why_oo_sucks)
- [Object Oriented Programming: The Wrong Path?](http://www.infoq.com/news/2010/07/objects-smalltalk-erlang)
- [Why I Program In Erlang](http://www.evanmiller.org/why-i-program-in-erlang.html)

This should give you the basic idea, why objects with getters and setters aren't supported. The closest thing to having an object with state is to have a [server](http://elixir-lang.org/getting_started/mix_otp/8.html#8.1-echo-server) with state. So in server loop, you can do something like this:

```
def loop(state) do
  newstate = receive do
    { :get_property_one, pid } ->
      pick_the_property_from_state_and_send_to_pid(state, pid)
      state
    { :set_property_one } ->
      set_property_one_and_return_new_state(state)
  end
  loop(newstate)
end
```

Spawning new server with initial state is close to createing new object using constructor. Sending `:get_property_one` is like getter, but asynchronous (you can do something else before waiting for reply). Sending `:set_property_one` doesn't wait for reply, so it is non blocking.

This might look cumbersome, but it solves couple of problems:

- you will not have readers, writers problem in Erlang, because all the requests are processed one by one
- if your getters and setters require some complex operations, they can be done asynchronously (without blocking the calling process)

This pattern is so common, that there is [`behaviour` called `gen_server`](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/genserver.html), that eliminates most of the boilerplate of looping. If you still think, that there is too much boilerplate to write, you can read [my article about it](http://tkowal.wordpress.com/2014/09/09/erlang-otp-gen_server-boilerplate/) (this one is in Erlang)

Comment: it seems that links of behaviour called gen_server is 404

Comment: Thanks! Updated the link. :)

Answer (score 3):

The closest to `OO` I think you can get would be this

```
defmodule Config do

  defstruct [
    some_property: nil,
    other_property: nil
  ]

  def new(one, two) do
    %Config{
      some_property: one,
      other_property: two
    }
  end

  #Getter
  def property_one(this) do 
    this.some_property
  end

  #Setter
  def property_one(this, value) do 
    %{this | some_property: value}
  end
end
```

And you have to use it like this

```
conf = Config.new("a", 2)
Config.property_one(conf) # == "a"
conf = Config.property_one(conf, "b") # == %Config{some_property: "b", other_property: 2}
```

As you see they are just functions that extract/integrate some information around/into structs. I love getters and setters in C# and Dart, but in the FP world they are just functions, no more no less.